# Norm, gradient, vector

Tags: normed-spaces, vector-analysis

Can I say that the norm of a component of the vector is smaller than the norm of the whole vector? (in this case the gradient)

$$\|v_x\| < \|\operatorname{grad} v\|$$

Comment: It's a little bit odd, I must say: comparing the norm of an entry versus the norm of a matrix with all the first-order partial derivatives of the vector entries…

Comment: I would like to know if is correct this $$||v_x ||_{L^2} ≤||∇v||_{L^2} $$ in order to apply Lax Milgram

Answer (score 1):

Less than or equal to, but yes. Consider $v =\langle 1,0\rangle$. This has a 2-Norm of 1 and an infinity Norm (largest single component) of 1 as well.